# add extra widgetized area below category name in storefront

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, widget, storefront

I'd like to add a widgetized area just below the category name on the pages showing the products listing. I am using a child theme of storefront 2.4.1.
I tried several hooks listed [here](https://github.com/woocommerce/storefront/blob/master/inc/storefront-template-hooks.php) and [here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/storefront-hooks-actions-filters/) (why are there two different lists by the way??) but in vain.

```
// Adding the widget area.
if (function_exists('register_sidebar')) {
    register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => 'Extra Widget Area below category title',
    'id' => 'extra-widget-area',
    'description' => 'Extra Widget Area below category title',
    'before_widget' => '<div class="widget my-extra-widget">',
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
    'before_title' => '<h2>',
    'after_title' => '</h2>'
    ));
}
// placing the widget
add_action ('storefront_homepage_after_product_categories_title', 'add_my_widget_area');
// add_action ('homepage', 'add_my_widget_area', 10);
function add_my_widget_area() {
  if (function_exists('dynamic_sidebar')) {
    dynamic_sidebar('Extra Widget Area below category title');
  }
}
```